# SPARQL: Inverse result on boolean query

Tags: sparql, rdf, allegrograph

I am trying to have SPARQL return 'false' if a set of triples exist in an RDF database. I'm able to return 'true' with an ASK query.

```
ASK WHERE { ?subjID rdf:type pref:Person. }
```

As described [here](https://www.w3.org/2009/sparql/wiki/Design:Negation), I tried adding NOT EXISTS { } inside of the WHERE, but this results in an error.

```
ASK WHERE { NOT EXISTS { ?subjID rdf:type pref:Person. } }
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation that I linked doesn't describe this but you must put FILTER in front of NOT EXISTS.

```
ASK WHERE { FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subjID rdf:type pref:Person. } }
```

Comment: the documentation that you referred to was an old draft. The "correct" sources to look into are always the official docs, i.e. in your case the [W3C recommendation of SPARQL 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/)

Comment: That said, I don't think your solution works. I mean, it applys the filter on what? There is no solution mapping during the evaluation of the `exists` filter. You can check `ASK WHERE { FILTER EXISTS { ?subjID rdf:type pref:AClassThatDoesNotExist. } }` as a counter example, it always returns returns `true` for an arbitrary class not in the dataset. Afaik, the should be a generic `?s ?p ?o` triple pattern before: `ASK WHERE { ?subjID ?p ?o FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subjID rdf:type pref:Person. } }`

Comment: @AKSW there is no need of an artifical statement pattern in front of the filter - a simple singleton `{}` will be enough (in case, the tool parsing the sparql do not introduce such by default

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov hm, ok. on DBpedia endpoint I tried `ASK WHERE { {} FILTER EXISTS { ?s rdf:type dbo:NonExistingClass. } }` vs `ASK WHERE { ?s ?p ?o FILTER EXISTS { ?s rdf:type dbo:NonExistingClass. } }` - only the second returns `false` which is correct.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov but on Wikidata it works as you said, But on Wikidata it works as you said `ASK WHERE { {} FILTER EXISTS { ?s wdt:P31 <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/NonExistingClass> } }` returns `false`. So I guess it's something wrong in Virtuoso?

Comment: @ASKW the query in the answer is perfectly correct. The `WHERE` clause is a valid BGP (a single solution of an empty set of bindings) with a `FILTER` that should be evaluated over it. I've suggested an explicit use of the empty BGP `{}` as a possible workaround. The query from the answer works correctly on Wikidata service, so it is very likely a bug with the dbpedia sparql service.

Comment: `ASK WHERE { FILTER NOT EXISTS { ?subjID rdf:type pref:Person. } }` is a reasonable query. `NOT EXISTS` matches the pattern given which can contain variables. The `FILTER` tests the resuls of the empty pattern (one row, no variables) and if it passes the filter, `ASK` is true. The filter is "yes" for nothing matching `?subjID rdf:type pref:Person` and "no" if there are any  matching triples.

Comment: @DamyanOgnyanov ok, then public DBpedia endpoint resp. its Virtuoso backend is wrong ... nevertheless, for me this syntax isn't really intuitive: I mean doing a FILTER  like `ASK WHERE { FILTER (  EXISTS { ?s a <Class>. }) }`on virtually "nothing" looks a bit weird. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: "Perfectly correct" must be taken with a grain of salt when it is **not** compatible with a major triple store like Virtuoso. "Correct according to the standard", yes, but support by real-life infrastructure is more important for a solution.